# Wrong month with moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

[The docs for moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/) say one way to create a moment object is by passing in an array.

However, if I do this for Jan 1, 2017 in this way, I get an unexpected result:

```
moment([2017,1,1]).toString()
```

... leads to the result of "Wed **Feb** 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0600"

Am I doing something wrong here, or is it a bug in the library?

I'm using version 2.17.1 in Firefox, and also got same results with 2.18.1 in Chrome on a different computer with a different OS.
I'm using v 2.17.1.

Comment: Months are zero-indexed, so January is `0` and December is `11`. See the [note in the Array section](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/).

Comment: @4castle my apologies, you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it uses the JavaScript interpretation of a month and 0-indexes the month. So 0 = January, 1 = February, etc.